# Как правильно упаковать файлы в rpm пакет?

Tags: linux, centos, rpm

Мне нужно упаковать в rpm файлы и папки (java приложение в виде jar файла, библиотек к нему, help и т.п., и пару файлов со скриптами). Делаю все под Linux CentOS 6.7

Все проходит нормально за исключением двух файлов (mapexporter.sh и mapexporter.desktop - они содержат скрипты). Мне нужно, чтобы эти два файла оказались внутри rpm в определенных папках:

```
.../bin/mapexporter.sh

.../share/applications/mapexporter.desktop
```

Происходит такая штука: rpm файл собирается, но у него внутри оказывается, что *вместо `/bin/mapexporter.sh` лежит файл `bin` без расширения и содержит скрипт из файла `mapexporter.sh`. И оказывается файл `applications` тоже без расширения, в котором содержится скрипт из файла `mapexporter.desktop`.*

Т.е., папка, содержащая файл со скриптом как-то поглощает этот файл и сама становится файлом.

Как этого избежать?

При этом все остальные файлы упаковываются в rpm без проблем. В моем случае используется только 2 файла со скриптами и с обоими одна и та же проблема.

Делаю все традиционным образом: создаю дерево папок (`BUILD, RPMS, RPMS, SOURCES, SRPMS, SPECS`), кладу нужные мне файлы в папку `SOURCES` в виде `.tar`, в папку `SPECS` кладу `.spec файл` с инструкциями по сборке пакета.

Собираю пакет командой:

```
rpmbuild -bb mapexporter.spec
```

Процесс сборки проходит без ошибок. Rpm файл создается и содержит нужную мне структуру за исключением этих двух файлов со скриптами.

Прикладываю содержимое spec-файла (данные о лицензии и производителе из описания удалил, т.к. не имеют отношения к вопросу):

```
Summary: 
Name: 
Version: 8.2.0
Release: 1
License: 
Group: Applications
URL: 
Distribution: WSS Linux
Vendor: 
Packager: 
Source0: mapexporter-8.2.0.tar
BuildRoot: /home/honsu/projects/rpm/tmp/mapexporter-root


%description
Application for working with geo-space information

%prep
%setup -q %{name}-%{version}

%build

%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/mapexporter
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/mapexporter/extlibs
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/share
cp -r /home/honsu/projects/rpm/BUILD/mapexporter-8.2.0/map_exporter.jar $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/mapexporter
cp -r /home/honsu/projects/rpm/BUILD/mapexporter-8.2.0/ChangeLog.txt $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/mapexporter
cp -r /home/honsu/projects/rpm/BUILD/mapexporter-8.2.0/version.txt $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/mapexporter
cp -r /home/honsu/projects/rpm/BUILD/mapexporter-8.2.0/help $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/mapexporter
cp -r /home/honsu/projects/rpm/BUILD/mapexporter-8.2.0/configs $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/mapexporter
cp -r /home/honsu/projects/rpm/BUILD/mapexporter-8.2.0/linux64 $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/mapexporter/extlibs/linux64
cp -r /home/honsu/projects/rpm/BUILD/mapexporter-8.2.0/mapexporter.sh $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/bin
cp -r /home/honsu/projects/rpm/BUILD/mapexporter-8.2.0/mapexporter.desktop $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/share/applications

%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
/usr/local/mapexporter/map_exporter.jar
/usr/local/mapexporter/ChangeLog.txt
/usr/local/mapexporter/version.txt
/usr/local/mapexporter/help
/usr/local/mapexporter/configs
/usr/local/mapexporter/extlibs/linux64
/usr/local/bin
/usr/share/applications

%post
semanage fcontext -a -t lib_t /usr/local/mapexporter/extlibs(/.*)?
restorecon -vR /usr/local/mapexporter
echo ’mapexporter’ >> /usr/share/gnome-panel/mac-panel-exec

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
```

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, spec-файл. без его полного содержимого вряд ли можно что-то вам посоветовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. в секции `%files` вы включили каталоги, но не включили файлов:

   ```
   %files
   ...
   /usr/local/bin
   /usr/share/applications
   ```

   включать в эту секцию эти каталоги, насколько мне известно, не надо.

   зато точно надо включить необходимые файлы:

   ```
   %files
   ...
   /usr/local/bin/mapexporter.sh
   /usr/share/applications/mapexporter.desktop
   ```
2. вы пытаетесь копировать файлы в несуществующие каталоги:

   ```
   cp -r /home/honsu/projects/rpm/BUILD/mapexporter-8.2.0/mapexporter.sh $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/bin
   cp -r /home/honsu/projects/rpm/BUILD/mapexporter-8.2.0/mapexporter.desktop $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/share/applications
   ```

   вот у вас и записывается содержимое файла `mapexporter.sh` в **файл** `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/bin`, а содержимое файла `mapexporter.desktop` — в **файл** `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/share/applications`.

   вам надо предварительно создать **каталоги** `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/bin` и `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/share/applications` (как вы делаете выше для других каталогов).
3. указывать путь к каталогу сборки (`/home/honsu/projects/rpm/BUILD/mapexporter-8.2.0/`) в spec-файле неправильно и не требуется: во время исполнения команд из секции `%install` этот каталог и так является текущим. достаточно и так (и финальный слэш, кстати, поможет избежать ошибки из пункта два моего ответа):

   ```
   cp -r map_exporter.jar $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/mapexporter/
   ```

   и далее по аналогии.
4. и вообще лучше использовать для инсталляции файлов не программу `cp`, а программу `install`. в частности, она позволяет указывать необходимый набор прав у файла. посмотрите образцы spec-файлов из пакетов своего дистрибутива и, конечно, `man install`.

---

дополнение к пункту 2 (с учётом пункта 4):

при использовании программы `install` можно передать ей опцию `-D`. тогда второй параметр будет рассматриваться как каталог, и он, при необходимости, будет создан, включая все недостающие части.

после выполнения этой команды будут созданы каталоги `/some`, `/some/long` и `/some/long/path`, а затем файл `somefile` будет скопирован в каталог `/some/long/path`:

```
install -D somefile /some/long/path
```

заметьте: в этом случае можно обойтись и без предварительного вызова `mkdir`.

Comment: Изначально у меня так и было:

`%files
...
/usr/local/bin/mapexporter.sh
/usr/share/applications/mapexporter.desktop`

Но это приводило к описанному мной результату. Убрал названия файлов из раздела %files, надеясь, что сработает по аналогии с другими папками. Но не сработало.

Т.е. пробовал и прописывать путь к файлу, и путь к папке. Результат одинаковый.

Comment: на сколько знаю, включать полный список файлов необязательно, можно указать просто директорию и файлы рекурсивно будут добавлены из этой директории.

Comment: Да, так и есть. Если указать просто директорию, то все файлы из нее добавляются рекурсивно. На это и рассчитывал.

Comment: @Alex, я дополнил ответ.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, вы правы! Пункт 2 из вашего дополнения решил проблему - предварительно не были созданы папки.
Остальные ваши рекомендации сейчас по изучаю и буду оптимизировать свой spec-файл.
Спасибо!

Comment: @Alex, я внёс ещё одно дополнение. в частности, касающееся и пункта 2.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov, теоретически вы правы. но, насколько я помню, не во всех дистрибутивах (или версиях rpm?) такое допустимо. поэтому, мне кажется, указание файлов (хотя бы по маске `*`) — будет надёжнее.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста!  
Как будет выглядеть команда install если мне нужно скопировать директорию, а не файл:  
`install -D someFolder /some/long/path`

Comment: @Alex, вам требуется рекурсивное копирование? нет, программа `install` этого не умеет. она предназначена для *инсталляции* файлов (при необходимости, меняя права на них и принадлежность, а также производя ещё некоторые «хитрости»).